# Schengen visa for two stopovers in Germany

Tags: visas, transit, eu

I will be traveling internationally to Frankfurt and transiting to Munich by air before flying internationally. Do I need a visa to travel fly between Frankfurt and Munich? I have a US visa.

Comment: Your citizenship will determine the answer. What country's passport do you carry?

Comment: Having a US visa won't help you; what matters is which passport you'll be using.  (If you meant to type "US passport" then you don't need a visa for two stopovers in Germany.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a C (visitor) visa, a A (transit) visa only applies to when you're staying in the international transit zone of an airport ([link](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa/airport-transit-visa/924624))

From the PDF in the above link (emphasis mine)

> **Airport transit privilege does not apply and you will need a visitor visa if**
> [...]
> 2. you are transiting through two or more airports in the Schengen Countries (for
> example: Miami-Frankfurt-Paris-India or **New York-Frankfurt-Munich-India**)

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica your comment is well taken, but you've mixed up "Annex I" and "Annex II."  The current consolidated version of the regulation that establishes these lists is available at https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02018R1806-20210101

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the correction, you're exactly right. I'll delete and repost my comment.

Comment: This Answer is not necessarily correct. The correct answer depends upon the OP's citizenship. If of an Annex I country, a visa is required. If of an Annex II country, a visa is not required.